# URL - Get last part in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, url

I have my url:

```
http://domain/fotografo/admin/gallery_bg.php
```

and i want last part of the url:

```
 gallery_bg.php
```

but, I do not want to link static, ie, for each page that vistitar I want to get the last part of the url

Answer (score 38, accepted):

use following

```
<?php
    $link = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $link_array = explode('/',$link);
    echo $page = end($link_array);
?>
```

Comment: Didnt work cause my link ended up with a / example : **https/mysite.com/products/my-name/** I tried the solution of @jaydeep here with "basename" it's faster and works perfectly !

Answer (score 39):

Use basename function

```
echo basename("http://domain/fotografo/admin/gallery_bg.php");
```

Comment: this is very efficient and fast

Comment: @farhang it depends what you want it to do. For me $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] was what I needed .....

Comment: Worked for me as the **validated answer** did not because my link ended up with a **/** while I needed the last element whether there is one or not. Thank you !

Answer (score 11):

If it is same page:

```
echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

or

echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];

or 

echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
```

In each case a back slash(`/`gallery_bg.php) will appear. You can trim it as

```
echo trim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],"/");
```

---

or split the url by `/` to make an array and get the last item from array

```
$array = explode("/",$url);

$last_item_index = count($url) - 1;

echo $array[$last_item_index];
```

or

```
echo basename($url);
```

Comment: If you write URI as "https//server/myscript and it is redirected with .htaccess to lets say to https//server/some.php  the only that will work and give you "myscript" is the $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], the other suggestions will return "some.php"

Answer (score 7):

```
 $url = "http://domain/fotografo/admin/gallery_bg.php";
 $keys = parse_url($url); // parse the url
 $path = explode("/", $keys['path']); // splitting the path
 $last = end($path); // get the value of the last element
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use basename($url) function as suggested above. This returns the file name from the url. You can also provide the file extension as second argument to this function like basename($url, '.jpg'), then the filename without the extension will be served.

Eg:

```html
$url = "https://i0.com/images/test.jpg"

then echo basename($url) will print test.jpg

and echo basename($url,".jpg") will print test
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$url  = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
$path = explode("/", $url); 
$last = end($path);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Here you have 2 options.

1. Using explode function.

$filename = end(explode('/', 'http://domain/fotografo/admin/gallery_bg.php'));

2. Use basename function.

$filename = basename("http://domain/fotografo/admin/gallery_bg.php");
```

-
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    $basepath = implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), 0, -1)) . '/';
    $uri = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen($basepath));
    if (strstr($uri, '?')) $uri = substr($uri, 0, strpos($uri, '?'));
    $url = trim($uri, '/');
```

In PHP 7 the accepted solution is giving me the error that only variables are allowed in explode so this works for me.