# get last part of url dynamic

Tags: php, url

I found a way to get the last part of the url, I just don't know if there's an even better way since I want it to be dynamic.

This is the way I did it:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$categoryName = basename($url);
```

The last part of the url in this case is always a category(horror for e.g) that's in my database, so the url will always looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/blog/public/index.php/categories/Horror
```

or

```
http://localhost:8888/blog/public/index.php/categories/Fantasy
```

I think you got my point.

Well, the question is, is there a better way or is mine okay? Especially when looking at the

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Comment: Do you mean **Horror** and **Fantasy** by **category-name**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL - Get last part in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541080/url-get-last-part-in-php). You can see multiple method in it

Comment: @Mohammad that question is about getting the filename, not the query string portion of a seo-friendly url.

Answer (score 0):

Use `explode()` to split URL by `/` delimiter and use `end()` to get last item of array.

```
$url = "http://localhost:8888/blog/public/index.php/categories/Horror";
$categoryName = @end(explode("/", $url));
// Horror
```

Comment: Isn't this just exactly what basename() does?

Comment: @ofmiceandmoon Yes, both return same result in this case

Comment: what's the advantage of using explode() in this case?

Comment: @ofmiceandmoon It does not prefered to `basename()` in this case, but is another method

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a simple regex to get it.

```
$re = '@.*/(.*)@m';
$str = 'http://localhost:8888/blog/public/index.php/categories/Horror';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

echo $matches[0][1];
//outputs `Horror`
```

Comment: that's not exactly what I meant; I know I can do it different ways with basename, explode and others; I want to always get the last part, wheter it's "Horror" or "Fantasy". I've make it work with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and wanted to know if there is a better way.

Comment: well, you can always make your http server to parse it for you and pass it to your index.php as query string and get it from `$_GET`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using laravel or symphony use `end(Request::segments())`

Comment: I made my own framework, but soon I'm going to work with Laravel, so Thank you :)

Comment: `<?php
    $link = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $link_array = explode('/',$link);
    echo $page = end($link_array);
?>` Then go with this core php

Comment: Looks like an answer to me. (It probably got auto-flagged because it's short.)