# How to get react URL in php for creating API?

Tags: php, regex, url

I want to get a URL which is coming from a React rout. 
URL is like: `http://localhost:3001/users/[member_username]` 
In which `member_username` will be dynamic as per the user name.

So for example if a url hit like `http://localhost:3001/users/gray` then a variable will get `gray` or url hit like `http://localhost:3001/users/john` then a variable will get `john`

Now i need to get that url into WordPress php file to create an API.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19541080/7995957) solution but did not getting the exact solution that is fit to my problem.

Here is my API code that in which i need to get URL.

```
function get_user_id(){
$server_name = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$user_name = basename("http://".$server_name."/users/admin");

// For now i have set the username as static, so it should be a dynamic as user hit the url. 

  $users = get_user_by('login', $user_name);

  if( !empty($users) ){

    foreach ($users as $key => $user) { 
      $user_name = new stdClass();
      $user_name->id = $user->ID;
      $user_name->user_login = $user->user_login;
      $user_name->user_nicename = $user->user_nicename;
      $user_name->user_email = $user->user_email;
      return $user_name;
    }
  }

}
/*
 *
 * Add action endpoint building
 *
 */
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'rest-endpoints/v1', '/userid', array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'get_user_id'
    ));
});
```

Comment: Based on the SO ref you gave and solutions that didn't work...: can you elaborate any information and/or error(-log) that it produced for you? Please make your question tag more specific and make sure others can reproduce your error (i.e. complete code?). Right-now its too general. End of triage review > requires editing.

Comment: I have edit my question add add the code part for more justification. 
I am not getting an error, but my question is how can get a url last term from a remote url ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you let me know why that solution not fit for your problem?
seems is ok to get the username.

however, maybe you can try this

```
<?php
$url = parse_url('http://localhost:3001/users/yourname',PHP_URL_PATH);
$url = str_replace("/users/","",$url);
echo $url;
?>
```

Comment: `yourname` is dynamic, so how can i get that last term dynamic?

Comment: @GrayCarry: you mean that `yourname` could actually be something like `a/b/c`? and you would like to get `c`?

Comment: yes the last part of the url will be dynamic... 
so it should be change as per the username same like Facebook user profile. It has the first part a constant url (eg https://www/facebook.com/zuck or https://www/facebook.com/allan ) and the username will be passed dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$url_path = parse_url('http://localhost:3001/users/a13/abc',PHP_URL_PATH);
$url = preg_replace("/\/(?:[^\/]*\/)*/","",$url_path);
echo $url;
```

**output:**

```
abc
```

**demo**: https://regex101.com/r/19x7ut/1/

or this regex:

```
\/(?:[^\/\s]*\/)*
```

**demo:** https://regex101.com/r/19x7ut/3/

both should work fine.

Comment: I want dynamic value which will concat after a constant url path that is  `http://localhost:3001/users/[member_username]` so is there any PHP function that will return a value which will get that dynamic username value ?